# Rails - pdfkit generate an image as header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, header-files, pdfkit

I want to generate pdf file with an image as header in each page

```
def download_contract
  @campaign = Campaign.find_by_id(params['campaign_id'])
  html = render_to_string partial: 'campaign_shoppers/contract', locals: {contract:     @campaign.contract}
  kit = PDFKit.new(html, :header_right => **Here i want to display an image**)
  send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "contract_campaign_#{@campaign.title}.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'attachment')  
end
```

But I can't generate pdf file with option 'header_right' is image( text is fine).
Any suggestion? Thanks a lot